# How to get country code from IP using here.com API?

Tags: ip-geolocation

I am working on https://developer.here.com/documentation#services, to get Location of a user, trying to get country code from IP

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Here.com does not provide an IP geolocation API. It mainly focus on forward and reverse geocoding.

However, there exists several IP geolocation providers: Ipregistry, IpInfo, IpData, Maxmind, Ip2location, etc.

Here is an example using Ipregistry (disclaimer, I am working for):

```js
fetch('https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (payload) {
        console.log(payload.location.country.code);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here.com does not provide location of the user from an IP address, for that you have to use an IP geolocation service, like our service, [IPinfo](https://www.ipinfo.io).

If you have the IP address of the user it is quite easy to get the location information, such as:

- City
- Region
- Country
- Latitude and longitude

Here.com can take these information and process it as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html).

If you chose to use IPinfo, you can make an API request to the `ipinfo.io/<ip_address>` endpoint. If you are going to lookup IP geolocations quite frequently, I recommend you sign up so that you can get 50,000 IP geolocation lookups for free per month.

If you want the full IP address location, try:

```bash
curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
```

The `8.8.8.8` is a dummy IP Address. The response from the API lookup would be like so:

```json
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "dns.google",
  "anycast": true,
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.4056,-122.0775",
  "org": "AS15169 Google LLC",
  "postal": "94043",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
}
```

If you want just the `country` information, you can make an API call to the `country` endpoint like so:

```bash
curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/country
```

This will return a string/text like:

```
US
```